# Having trouble figuring out this DFS riddle

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

> ```
> one of the df trees consists of only one vertex v though v has both 
> incoming and outgoing edges without a self-loop. 
> Write G and its df forest.
> ```

How can a vertex possibly have outgoing edge, but be the only vertex in the tree? Do cross edges not count, or is there a more clever solution?

Answer (score 0):

A DFS tree usually is defined to just contain the nodes that were visited by forward edges, not cross edges. As a hint: if there's an edge (v, u) and DFS is started on u, then u won't appear in v's DFS tree.

Hope this helps!